# Gmail screen has reduced

Tags: display, problem-step-recorder

My platform is Windows Vista Home, browser is Chrome.

My Gmail page has suddenly reduced in size so even when the expand button is clicked there is still about 2 inches of blank space below the toolbar, All other pages from other sites are displayed correctly. How do I restore the Gmail screen to full size?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? You can use [Google’s Screen Capture](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cpngackimfmofbokmjmljamhdncknpmg) extension to easily take a screenshot and blur/redact sensitive information.

Comment: Try pressing `CTRL + 0`

Answer (score 1):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> or use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> to resize the page when you are viewing Gmail.

Comment: What does that have to do with this problem? Resizing always pegs the page to the top-left of the window, so there would not blank space *above* it (let alone in the middle of the page as I suspect is the case).

Comment: I would start with a simple possible fix first, esp sense we do not have a lot to go from except to assume what the problem is... and most of these types of issues are text size or zooming when a key combo was accidently pressed.

Comment: Yes, except that like I said, resizing the screen small does [*not* add space *above* the content](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4jiZF.png).

Answer (score 1):

That’s probably just a banner ad that is being blocked from loading by one of your extensions. There’s a few options available:

- Try updating your blocker extension to see if it was a bug that was fixed
- Try clearing your browser cache to load new ads/copy of GMail since the old one may have been buggy/corrupted
- Try disabling your ad-blocker
- Use another extension to hide the ad-bar. You can also use a user-stylesheet to set the bar to hidden (`div.aBC {display:none;}`)